# How do I preserve localtime() as an int when printing?

Tags: perl, localtime

I'm trying to append the integral return value of localtime (in Perl) but I can't seem to avoid it converting the return val to something that looks like this: Sun Jul 26 16:34:49 2009
When I say print localtime I see what I want, but when I say
$foo = localtime,""; print $foo; I get the string.
I want those digits.  I tried $foo = localtime() * 1 but that reverts to 1969 AND gets the string.

Very confusing.

Comment: `print localtime` does not return what you think it does; that's a list of numbers all run together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That string is what [`localtime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#localtime) returns in a scalar context. It returns

```
( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) = localtime();
```

in a list context. If you want just the timestamp, use [`time`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#time).

Answer (score 4):

Perl treats things differently depending on *context*. In scalar context, `localtime` returns a string representing the current (local) time. In list context, it returns a list of the various fields that make up a time value.

This problem arises because of the syntax of [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html).

```
    * print FILEHANDLE LIST
    * print LIST
    * print
```

Since `print` expects a list, this puts `localtime` in list context, so it returns a list of digits representing the seconds, minutes, hours, and so on, which are then concatenated by the `print` function. When assigning to a scalar, `localtime` is in scalar context and returns the string. If you want the concatenation of those digits, you can do something like

```
my $foo = join '', localtime;
print $foo;
```

However, perhaps a proper epoch time value would be more useful for whatever you're doing. In that case you can use `time` instead.

Comment: yeah, I misunderstood what those digits were. I thought it was a millisecond stamp. I realize now it's totally not what I wanted, whereas 'time' is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you think you know what a function does, but it isn't doing that, check the documentation. I frequently check the [localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) docs because I can never remember in what order the values come out.